# Opencv calcOpticalFlowPyrLK have got a bidirectional error as Matlab Computer Vision Toolbox?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, tracking

I'm using opencv 3.0.

I used the klt to track features:

```
Size winSize(11, 11);
int maxLevel = 4;
TermCriteria termcrit(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 30, 0.01);
int flags = 0; 
double minEigThreshold = 0.0001;
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(previous_gray, current_gray, previous_corners, current_corners, status, err, winSize, maxLevel, termcrit, flags, minEigThreshold);
```

I eliminated vectors with status == 0, but I still have some outliers.
Trying to use same parameters, but in Matlab, I obtain similar vectors, but without outliers.
I also tried to use flags = OPTFLOW_LK_GET_MIN_EIGENVALS and vary minEigThreshold, but without success

In Matlab I used:

```
tracker = vision.PointTracker('MaxBidirectionalError',0.5,'BlockSize',[11 11],'NumPyramidLevels',4);
tracker.release();
initialize(tracker,Points,IM);
[points,validity] = tracker(currentframe);
```

Varying MaxBidirectionalError I eliminated the outliers.

Question is there is in opencv something similar to MaxBidirectionalError?

Thank you very much!
Joe

P.S. these are the output I obtained:

Opencv (there are some outliers):

[image]

Matlab (almost no outliers):
[image]

Input image (left)

[image]

Input Image (right)

[image]

Comment: Can u post original image?

Comment: I inserted the input images. You can see there is a zoom

Comment: what makes you think you're using v3.0? why not latest 3.x? why not latest 4.x?